# What Index should be created for this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I need help to figured it out what Index(es) I need to create to improve the performance of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.nif, F.nomef
FROM fornecedor F, produto P
WHERE F.nif = P.forn_primario AND P.categoria = 'Fruta';
```

The tables fornecedor and produto are created this way:

Fornecedor

```
create table fornecedor (
nif char(9) not null unique,
nomef varchar(80) not null,
constraint nif_size CHECK (Length(nif)=9),
constraint pk_fornecedor primary key(nif));
```

Produto

```
create table produto (
ean char(13) not null unique,
design varchar(255) not null,
categoria varchar(80) not null,
forn_primario char(9) not null,
data date not null,
constraint ean_size CHECK (Length(ean)=13),
constraint pk_produto primary key(ean),
constraint fk_produto_categoria foreign key(categoria) references categoria(nome) ON DELETE CASCADE,
constraint fk_produto_fornecedor foreign key(forn_primario) references fornecedor(nif));
```

I dont know if I need to create a Multiple-Key Index like:

```
CREATE INDEX multiple_idx ON produto (forn_primario,categoria);
```

or something else???

Comment: do you know the different values you can have for `producto.categoria` ? if you  can create an enum and index it or if the number of values for that column is huge and/or unknown you can have a table to all the categorias and a foreign key on the pk of that table from producto.

Comment: Before anything I can advice to **[NOT USE IMPLICIT JOINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)** that way you get your joins out of the `WHERE`clause and don't mix it with your filters

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need an index starting with `categoria`. The best will be with `forn_primario`:

```
 create index ix_producto_categoria on producto(categoria, forn_primario)
```

to further support your query you may want to create

```
 create index ix_fornecedor_nif on fornecedor(nif, nomef)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is better written as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.nif, F.nomef
FROM fornecedor F JOIN
     produto P
     ON F.nif = P.forn_primario AND P.categoria = 'Fruta';
```

For this version, you want indexes on `product(categoria, forn_primario)` and `fornecdor(nif)`.

Then, if `nif`/`nomef` is unique in the first table, it should be expressed as:

```
SELECT F.nif, F.nomef
FROM fornecedor F 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM produto P
              WHERE F.nif = P.forn_primario AND P.categoria = 'Fruta'
             );
```

For this version, you want an index on `produto(forn_primario, categoria)`.

Answer (score 0):

On fornecedor, the attribute nif is a primary key... i don't think you should use an index on a PK